# Shiny highlight certain dates in dateInput() preview

Tags: r, date, shiny

I want to highlight certain date values in color in the preview of the `dateInput()` function. The selected date always has a blue background. Now I would also like to highlight, for example, today's date in green and the 1st of the month in red. Unfortunately, this function does not have a default option for this.
Can anyone help me further?

[image]

Here is my reproducible example:

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    dateInput("date1", "Date:", value = Sys.Date()),
  )
  
  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means a complete solution, but might set you on your way or help someone else. It shows how you can colour a date using css. To explain a little, you can inspect elements by right clicking on them and you can see that each date has a `data-date` attribute which can be used to style them. The `data-date` values are unix timestamps so you should be able to work out what values to use.

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  green_date <- 1689811200000
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(type="text/css", paste0('[data-date="',green_date,'"] {background-color: #27ae60}')),
    dateInput("date1", "Date:", value = Sys.Date()),
  )
  
  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {

  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `datetimePickerInput` in the **shinyDatetimePickers** package, today's date is in yellow, and the days of the past month are greyed out. I know it's not a complete answer.

[image]